# How to hide root level when using MvcSiteMapProvider?

Tags: model-view-controller, hide, root, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MvcSiteMapProvider to create a simple breadcrumb. I'm having a small problem which I cant solve. Lets assume that my website contains five tabs: Home, Customer, Company, Reports and About (these are the top level tabs)

When a user is browsing the page Home, I don't want the breadcrumb to show up. However, when the user is on the page Customer,  the Breadcrumb should display "Home" (and the same applies to rest of the top level tabs - except Home of course). And for the next level, assuming the user has clicked on a link called "Customer Details" on the Customer page, the breadcrumb should display "Home / Customer". So basically, the top level is omitted.

How can I archive this? Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is just to edit the `SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml` template file in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` directory.

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@foreach (var node in Model) {
    // Condition to ensure root node is invisible 
    // when it is the current node
    if (!(node.IsRootNode && node.IsCurrentNode))
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => node);

        if (node != Model.Last()) {
            <text> &gt; </text>
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do it by making a custom [visibility provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#creating-a-custom-sitemapnodevisibilityprovider).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply! :)

I realized that something like this would also work:

```
@foreach (var node in Model.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse()) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node);
    if (node != Model.Last()) {
        <text> / </text>
    }
}
```